# How to give an SSH user being used by Bitbucket pipelines, access to only a specific directory?

Tags: linux, bitbucket, devops, ubuntu-18.04, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using bitbucket pipelines for CI/CD for our Laravel projects. I have successfully set up my bitbucket pipelines to automatically deploy to our digital ocean VPS, the pipelines first ssh into our server and then execute the `deploy.sh` shell script, already present on the VPS which pulls all the changes from the repo.

Now everything works perfectly, but I want to restrict the SSH users being used by the pipelines to only have access to the specific directory where the project is placed and not the entire server as then all users will be able to run pipelines and upload a deploy.sh to along with a push and execute commands on our server. Is there any way to protect our server against this and only restrict ssh to a specific directory only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common way of doing this in multi-user system is chroot-jail. However, for a VPS you can simply create a new user for pipelines. Store your deploy.sh in the home directory of this user, and deploy the project as well in the home directory of pipeline user.

Comment: Okay, I get the chroot-jail but in case we create a pipeline user, won't that mean that the user will be able to access the complete server and different sensitive files?